# ViewModel isn't being cleared after view is completely gone in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to understand why my `ViewModel` isn't cleared. I would suspect in the code below that the `onCleared` is called since the view is completely gone, but this does not happen, why not?

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val x = MutableStateFlow(0)

        setContent {
            ComposetestTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    val state = x.collectAsState().value

                    if (state % 2 == 0) {
                        StateZero()

                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            delay(1000)

                            x.value += 1
                        }
                    } else {
                        Text("NO")

                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            delay(1000)

                            x.value += 1
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun StateZero() {
    val viewModel: MyViewModel = viewModel()

    Text(text = "Should be clearing in a few seconds...")
}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()

        print("CLEARED")
    }
}
```

Comment: put this logic on second screen and then navigate back to first and check whether it clears the viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

`MainActivity` is provided by `LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current` to the `viewModel` function. So an instance of `MyViewModel` is created and stored into `MainActivity`, which makes the instance not invoke `onCleared`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1)), a ViewModel, including the one returned by `viewModel()`, is scoped to either an Activity or Fragment, not the Composable where `viewModel()` was called. So no matter where you call `viewModel()`, and regardless of whether it has exited the Composable, once the ViewModel instance is constructed, it stays in memory (doesn't get cleared) until the Activity/Fragment goes out of scope. Note, this wouldn't just be the Activity or Fragment instance. It would be the Activity or Fragment at that place in the task stack. So if an Activity is destroyed and recreated during a configuration change (such as a screen rotation), the ViewModel instance is kept.

Comment: Researching this did raise some new questions for me, though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76929515/why-should-viewmodel-only-be-used-at-the-root-composable-and-the-instance-neve