# Why should viewModel() only be used at the root composable and the instance never passed?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

[This documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel) about using ViewModel with Compose states:

> Note: Due to their lifecycle and scoping, **you should access and call ViewModel instances at screen-level composables**, that is, close to a root composable called from an activity, fragment, or destination of a Navigation graph. **You should never pass down ViewModel instances to other composables**, pass only the data they need and functions that perform the required logic as parameters.

However, [a ViewModel is scoped to the Activity or Fragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/viewmodel/compose/package-summary#viewModel(androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner,kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1)), so I would expect it to be OK if you call `viewModel()` wherever you like in the hierarchy, and even in multiple places in the same hierarchy. I would expect to be getting the same instance returned regardless.

1. What is the drawback of calling `viewModel()` deeper in the hierarchy than the root composable of a screen?
2. Why shouldn't a ViewModel instance be passed to a nested Composable?

The obvious drawback to following this advice is that you may have to do a lot of state hoisting, leading to Composables with many parameters that must be connected manually and correctly, making code less readable and maintainable.

Comment: My theory is that this advice isn't for avoiding a functional problem, but that it is only advising a way of organizing code. Since a ViewModel should be thought of as scoped to a screen, the individual pieces of UI in that screen *should not* have such a high level view of the data. Perhaps it is opinionated advice that doesn't get into the pros and cons?

Comment: The only useful thing i found other than clean code is your composable becomes easy for testing because you don't have to have the actual viewmodel to test with it instead you create a fake one.

Comment: i guess, it breaks separation-of-concerns principle and decrease reusable-ability?